# Area Select Leaflet Map Angular 9

Tags: angular, leaflet

I installed the leaflet-area-select (https://github.com/w8r/leaflet-area-select) plugin but when I define the select area I get the following error
[image]

I launched `npm install --save leaflet-area-select`

In angular.json I added

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
   "node_modules/leaflet-area-select/dist/Map.SelectArea.min.js",
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
],
```

And in the code the instructions that I added are these:

```
import SelectArea from 'leaflet-area-select';
public map: L.map;
this.map = L.map('map', {
   center: [37.606655, 15.1606003],
   selectArea: true,
   zoom: 10
});
    
this.map.on('areaselected', (e) => {
   console.log(e.bounds.toBBoxString()); // lon, lat, lon, lat
});
    
this.map.selectArea.setCtrlKey(true);
```

It seems that SelectArea is not recognized

[image]

If I move the mouse on the row,
**'SelectArea' is declared but its value is never read** appears

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like TS issue in recognizing types, alternatively you can use RequireJS. So install node type `npm install @types/node --save` and then in tsconfig file add node in types.

```
"types": [
      "node"
 ]
```

then use it like node require rather than commonjs style

```
var L = require("leaflet")
```

Otherwise if you want to stick to commonjs style, then you can create own `.d.ts` (*definition file*) file using module aigmentation

```
declare module leaflet 
{       
}
```

then import it like, that should work.

```
import * as L from 'leaflet'
```

and finally you also need to add this custom type path in tsconfig.json to make it work.

```
"typeRoots": [ "./your_custom_type_folder_here", "./node_modules/@types"]
```